# Microsoft Project Standard 2010 - set start time by clock not calendar

Tags: microsoft-project-2010

sI have a project that I need to run 24/7 with no breaks.  I need to set task start times at specific times of day.  How can I do that?

IE. if task 1 takes 4 hours and task 2 takes 3 hours; how can I set task 1 to start at 6AM and task 2 at to start at 10AM?

ADDITIONAL PROBLEM:
I have set the project to work through weekend but it won't schedule weekends.

Answer (score 5):

1. Set the project calendar (Project Tab, Project Information) to the
   24 hours calendar.
2. Turn on the display of time plus date in File >
       Options, General under date format.